# how to get original image using wp_get_attachment_image_src

Tags: images, attachments

I want to get the original image with the same width and height as uploaded.

My original image is 630*370.

Using the following function call I get a thumbnail sized at 630*198.

```php
wp_get_attachment_image_src($PriImgId,array('630','370'));
```

How can I get it at 630*370

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try this :

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $PriImgId, 'full' );
```

Also, for more options see the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src).

Comment: wp_get_attachment_image_src($PriImgId, 'full')[0]; will give the exact link

Comment: Yes it works fine, If no parameters is passed, wordpress will crop the image by default.

Answer (score 2):

There's [**wp_get_attachment_image_url**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/) introduced in WordPress 4.4.0.
It takes these arguments:

- *int* **$attachment_id** - Image attachment ID.
- *string|array* **$size** - Optional. Image size to retrieve. Accepts any valid image size, or an array of width and height values in pixels (in that order). Default 'thumbnail'.
- *bool* **$icon** - Optional. Whether the image should be treated as an icon. Default false.

Returns `string` (full attachment URL including domain) or `false` if no image was found.

Example uses:

```php
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachmentId, 'my-custom-size' );
$original = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachmentId, 'full' );
$square = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachmentId, [600, 600] );
```

Image sizes are usually defined in functions.php of your theme. WordPress documentation covers this in depth: [Post Thumbnails / Thumbnail Sizes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Thumbnail_Sizes)

If an array of two numbers (width and height) is passed into the function, it tries to find the closets matching size while preserving the aspect ratio.

Under the hood it uses [image_get_intermediate_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/image_get_intermediate_size/) to find the preferred size.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to remove the quotes on '630' and '370'.

Try this:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src($PriImgId,array( 630, 370 ) );
```